# Is there a continuous analogue of Ramanujan graphs?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I think it might help to think of the following definition of a Ramanujan graph - a graph whose non-trivial eigenvalues are such that their magnitude is bounded above by the spectral radius of its universal cover.

By "non-trivial eigenvalues" I mean all the eigenvalues except the highest and the smallest. A universal cover of a graph is the infinite tree such that every connected lift of the graph is a quotient of the tree. The spectral radius of a graph would be the norm of its adjacency matrix.

It would be helpful if people can give any pointers along these directions..

Comment: It would be helpful if the question were not merely in the title, but asked and expanded upon in the body of the question. It's hard figuring out what you want.

Answer (score 16):

In fact, the original motivation behind Lubotzky--Phillips--Sarnak's construction of Ramanujan graphs was in analogy with *modular curves* $Y(N)=\mathbb H^2/\Gamma(N)$ for the principal congruence subgroups $\Gamma(N)\subseteq\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$.  So the answer is yes, there is a continuous analogue, but in fact it came first!

Let me give a few more details.  The spectrum of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on hyperbolic space $\mathbb H^2$ consists of $[\frac 14,\infty)$.  Selberg proved that the smallest positive eigenvalue of the Laplacian on $Y(N)$ satisfies $\lambda_1(Y(N))\geq\frac 3{16}$, and conjectured that $\lambda_1(Y(N))\geq\frac 14$.  Note that $\frac 14$ is exactly the inf of the spectrum of $\Delta$ on the universal cover $\mathbb H^2$.  You can read more about this in an [article by Sarnak](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1355461).

As far as I understand things, Lubotzky--Phillips--Sarnak's examples of Ramanujan graphs are discrete analogues of modular curves.

Comment: Pradon Thanks for the explanations. But the link is not opening. Can you kindly link to some pedagogical article on this ? Something publicly available?

Answer (score 5):

One possible answer can be found in the theory of [graph limits](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=COLL-60), where large graphs are modelled by continuous objects.  In particular, a *graphing* is one type of continuous analogue of a graph, and it still makes sense to do spectral theory on graphings.  Thus, one can define a suitable notion of a *Ramanujan graphing*.  See Section 2 of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6784v1.pdf) of Backhausz, Szegedy and Virág, where this is carried out.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out
http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1028
It's Ramanujan complex

Comment: While the paper is interesting and relevant, as far as I can see, Ramanujan complexes are finite, so it's a generalization in a different direction than what the answer asks for.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: perhaps you rather mean "... than what the *question* asks for"?

Comment: if the author means a generalization to simplicial complexes then I guess there is not yet an agreement on the "right definition" of expanders (which Ramanujan graphs are extreme cases)

Comment: I believe the issue is that the author asks in the title for _continuous_ analogues, not higher-dimensional analogues.